# Multi-factor Authentication is not enabled issue

Tags: joomla-4.x, administrator, authentication

I'm facing challenges enabling Multi-factor Authentication (MFA) Code by Email for frontend users in Joomla. Despite following the necessary steps and configurations, I encounter persistent issues.

Here's a detailed breakdown of the problem:

Plugin Activation (001.png and 002.png): I activated the "Authentication Code by Email" option from the plugin list. However, upon navigating to the user details page and accessing the "Multi-factor Authentication" tab, a note message indicates: "Multi-factor Authentication is not enabled" (003.png).

Options Configuration (004.png and 005.png): I accessed the "Options" on the user list page and set "Enforce Multi-factor Authentication" to "Registered" users. Subsequently, frontend login attempts resulted in a message displaying: "Multi-factor Authentication is not enabled" (005.png).

Despite thorough configuration checks and attempts, the MFA Code by Email doesn't function as expected for frontend users after login.

I would highly appreciate any insights, troubleshooting steps, or guidance from the Joomla community on how to effectively enable Multi-factor Authentication via Email for frontend users.

My Joomla version 4.4.1 and also tested on joomla 5.1 with the same issue
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]